# Entity or ValueObject?

Tags: c#, ddd

Только начал вникать в DDD 
Есть две сущности оператор и диалог.
У оператора есть параметр Сектор, к которому относится оператор.
У диалога тоже есть такой параметр, определяет, на какой сектор поступило обращение.
По BL диалог может, отработать не обязательно оператор того же сектора.
В данном случае Sector будет Value Object или Entity?
Для оптимизации, то в таблице диалогов нет смысла хранить полное инфо о секторе, тогда Sector будет отдельной таблицей с полем id?
И если есть уже id то это уже сущность?
В дальнейшем, может появится ещё 1 сектор.
Вот здесь и запутался.

```
public class Operator // Entity
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public Sector Sector { get; }

    //ctor
    //methods
}

public class Dialog // Entity
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public int OperatorId { get; }
    public Sector Sector { get; }

    //ctor
    //methods
}

public class Sector // Entity? ValueObject?
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public Address Address { get; }
}
```

С Address я уже понял, что это будет ValueObject, т.к. по бл мне не важно это, только наличие его.

Comment: Если элементу нужен id - то это скорее всего entity. Если ему id отродясь не нужен, то скорее всего value object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ValueObject - уникальная и взаимозаменяемая штука.

Обычно это что-то элементарное, вида статус таски (В работе, закрыта, черновик).

Если ваши сектора - штука уникальная и например можно создать два абсолютно одинаковых, но ссылки при этом собственные (ну т.е. у двух операторов имя сектора одинаковое, адрес секторов одинаковый, но это разные записи) то это сущности.

Если сектора например создаются на создании базы данных, а потом оператор (или кто ещё) может их только выбирать из готового списка - скорее всего сгодится ValueObject.

В целом, я обычно иду от "сущностей". Является ли сектор - сущностью? Есть ли у него жизненный цикл? (черновик, утвержденная сущность, закрытая запись сущности) Есть ли разница между секторами по названию? (т.е. достаточно ли названия для уникальной идентификации или нет)

Плюс, учитывая неизменность ValueObject-ов, они часто зашиваются на уровне разработки, в отличие от сущностей.